# Is there any online API, which provides udated list of toll free and emergency numbers for different countries

Tags: web-services, api

I want to show a list of toll free and emergency numbers for different countries.
Is there any online API which provides me those numbers and regularly updates those numbers.
The list of Emergency numbers are available in wikipedia for all countries, but it would be nice if i can get those as a web-service.

Comment: Don't know why you people have closed this question. He is simply asking for a web-service which he/she can use for his app. Its just the digitised form of yellow pages. I know this kind of api is available for US!!

Comment: Its been long since this question is asked, but I have the same requirement as in the question asked. Did you find any API for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not Sure but i think you can use:

---

ro.ril.ecclist: list of valid Emergency Call Codes, for example, 911. Values are read from EF_ECC on the SIM and possibly supplmented by tables based on operator, network, or manufacturing code.